# Common basis property

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-geometry, posets

Let F be a field and let $U_1, \ldots, U_k$ be subspaces of $F^n$. Say that $U_1, \ldots, U_k$ has a common basis if there is a basis $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ of $F^n$ such that each $U_i$ is a span of some subset of $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$. Suppose $V_1,\ldots,V_p$ and $W_1,\ldots,W_q$ are subspaces such that:

1. For all $i$, $V_1,\ldots,V_p,W_i$ has a common basis.
2. $W_1 < W_2< \ldots < W_q$.

Is it true that $V_1,\ldots,V_p, W_1,\ldots,W_q$ has a common basis?

Comment: Is the existence of common basis equivalent to a family of conditions of type $U_i\cap \sum_{j\in J}U_j=\sum_{j\in J}U_i\cap U_j$ where $J$ is a subset of the set of indices, $i$ is an index?